# Deploy full-stack app with Heroku - Express back end, React front end?

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment, react-fullstack

I built my first full-stack app, with an Express back end and React front end, contained in the same project folder ([see GitHub repo](https://github.com/nataliecardot/infinite-scroll)). The front end is contained in a folder called `client`. 
I deployed the app from the root directory -- on the deployed site, it just says "Cannot GET /." 
The package.json in the front end portion has a proxy field that proxies requests to the back end. When I open the project on localhost, everything works correctly.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Try that fix in your backend `package.json` part. First, you want to get the backend set and then Heroku needs React to run. Heroku has some quirks to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- the "start": "node server" part was already in scripts, but I added "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build" and redeployed and it still just said Cannot GET /

Comment: Ok---so if it works locally but not on Heroku even after my suggestion, this is probably it: on `SETTINGS` on your Heroku deployment project page, go to the `CONFIG VARS` spot and manually type in your variables and values from your `config/server.js` file. Add the `process.env` stuff on Heroku and see if that works.

Comment: That was it, had to add the config vars, also had to add this in my server.js file for it to work:
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
Many thanks!